# karatsuba algorithm, Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

i'm write own variant of karatsuba algh, but can't make it work with realy big integers

```
'use strict';

const karatsuba = function (x, y) {
  if (x < 10 || y < 10) return x * y;

  const strX = String(x);
  const strY = String(y);

  const n = Math.min(strX.length, strY.length);
  const m = Math.ceil(n / 2);

  const leftX = strX.slice(0, strX.length - m),
        rightX = strX.slice(strX.length - m, strX.length),

        leftY = strY.slice(0, strY.length - m),
        rightY = strY.slice(strY.length - m, strY.length);

  const prod1 = karatsuba(leftX, leftY),
        prod2 = karatsuba(rightX, rightY),
        prod3 = karatsuba(addAny(leftX, rightX), addAny(leftY, rightY));

  const a = prod1 + String(Math.pow(10, 2 * m)).slice(1),
        b = (prod3 - prod1 - prod2) + String(Math.pow(10, m)).slice(1),
        ab = addAny(a, b);

  return addAny(ab, prod2);
};

function addAny(a, b) {
  const MAX_INT = 9007199254740992,
      intA = parseInt(a),
      intB = parseInt(b);

  if ((intA + intB) < MAX_INT) return intA + intB;

  return sumStrings(a + '', b + '');
}



function sumStrings(a, b) {
  let res = '', c = 0;

  a = a.split('');
  b = b.split('');

  while (a.length || b.length || c) {
    c += ~~a.pop() + ~~b.pop();
    res = c % 10 + res;
    c = c > 9;
  }

  return res.replace(/^0+/, '');
}
```

it works fine with ints like 3957322621233333 and 5548313756335578
but when i'm try use it with big ints like 76715432964249374812219365555 and 32141964835273822784327848699719 code crash with

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error in Node.js. The calculated result is wrong, though: `karatsuba('76715432964249374812219365555','32141964835273822784327848699719') == '1045731853714033916818600413783559075'`

Comment: this is my test cases:
a = 3957322621234423;
b = 7748313756335578;
res = 30662577304368647842211393201494;
console.log(karatsuba(a, b) == res);

 ---- working fine, and with the lowest numbers ----

a = 34215432964249374812219364786397;
b = 94541964835273822784327848699719;
res = 3234794260129733170788831535430575611379062580407060392628922443;

range error :(

Comment: Why do you think `(prod3 - prod1 - prod2)` would just work when otherwise you need to call a special function for string addition? Use the same for substraction as well.

Comment: Yes, your right i think, I thought about it too, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You omitted the quotation marks in your call, didn't you?

```
> katsuba(76715432964249374812219365555,32141964835273822784327848699719)
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at karatsuba (repl:2:5)
    at karatsuba (repl:16:15)
    at karatsuba (repl:17:9)
    at karatsuba (repl:17:9)
    at karatsuba (repl:17:9)
    at karatsuba (repl:17:9)
    at karatsuba (repl:17:9)
    at karatsuba (repl:17:9)
    at karatsuba (repl:17:9)
    at karatsuba (repl:17:9)
```

`76715432964249374812219365555` is bigger than `5**53`, the `MAX_INT` in your code. The number literal is implicitly converted to a floating point number `7.671543296424938e+28`, and your algorithm chokes on the number format.

Nevertheless, there is some error in your implementation, because the calculated result is wrong even if you use string literals:

```
> karatsuba('76715432964249374812219365555', '32141964835273822784327848699719')
'1045731853714033916818600413783559075'
```

instead of

```
'2465784748659709650840276767201870909665028593909797886779045'
```

Comment: yes, your right - even with string params, got wrong number... probably i'm need to use another function to work with string to substract the numbers, think the problem is here... and probably i must work here only with strings params. Thanks!

Comment: @vanless, Bergi already mentioned that you cannot use the built-in minus operator. One further error I see is in `String(Math.pow(10, m)).slice(1)`. Try what happens with `m=200`. You could use `Array(m+1).join('0')` instead.

Comment: oh, my god, THANKS! ITS WORKING!) guys i love u and stack overflow too soooo much)))